# filter a collection data value a promise

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to filter a values a promise I have this array id

```
ids= [
       [234, 235, 236],
       [237, 238, 239, 240],
       [241, 242, 243, 244, 245]]
```

I have this function she return products and prices I loop all item ids in promise to retrieve a collection price on each id

```
async getPricesAndProducts() {
      const Products = this.idProducts;
      const ids = this.ids;
      let promisesPrices = [];
      const app = { $axios: this.$axios };
      const promisesProducts = Products.map((product) =>
        endPoint.getProducts(app, product)
      );
      for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < ids[i].length; y++) {
          promisesPrices.push(endPoint.getPrices(app, ids[i][y])); // collection prices 
        }
      }
      return await Promise.all([promisesProducts, promisesPrices]);
    }
```

when i'm loop, my collection like this example

```
prices= [
       {id: 234, price: 123},
       {id: 235, price: 567},
       {id: 236, price: 567},
       {id: 237, price: 456},
       {id: 238, price: 678},
       {id: 239, price: 234},
       {id: 240, price: 432},
       {id: 241, price: 430},
       {id: 232, price: 460},...]
```

I want to return a min price in the result of promise a each array example of expected result

```
promisesPrices= [
            {id:234, price: 123} // min price ids  [234, 235, 236],
            {id:239, price: 234}, // min price ids [237, 238, 239, 240],
            {id: 241 price: 430} // min price ids  [241, 242, 243, 244, 245]
           ]
```

I'm do that inside Promise.all but is don't work Ihave this error
**TypeError: promisesPrices.then is not a function**

```
return await Promise.all([promisesProducts, promisesPrices.then((res) => {
          res.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev.price < curr.price ? prev : curr));
        })
       ]);
```

Please help me

Comment: promisesPrices is an array of Promises right? An array won't have a `.then`.

Comment: The argument to `Promise.all()` should be an array of promises. `[promisesProducts, promisesPrices]` is a 2-dimensional array of promises.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by building an array of product objects...

```
const ids= [ [234, 235, 236], [237, 238, 239, 240], [241, 242, 243, 244, 245] ];

// create a structure like this: { 234: { id: 234 }, 235: { id: 235 }, ... 
const products = ids.flat().reduce((acc, id) => {
  acc[id] = { id };
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Next, I'd build (and test!) a function that returns a promise to fetch pricing for a given product...

```
function updatePrice(product) {
  const app = { $axios: this.$axios };
  return endPoint.getPrices(app, product.id).then(result => {
    product.price = result.price;  // however you do this
  })
}
```

I left out your calls to `endPoint.getProducts` for the array you get from `this.idsProducts`. The OP mentions this in the code, but it wasn't clear how those results are used.

Now you're in a good position to get all of the pricing...

```
function getPricing() {
  const promises = Object.values(products).map(updatePrice);
  return Promise.app(promises);
}
```

With this, we get to the point of asking the original question: how to get the min price in each group. The problem should be easier since we're no longer tangled up with the async code...

```
function getMinPrices() {
  return getPricing().then(() => {
    // now products is { 234: { id: 234, price: 123 }, ...
    const groupedByIds = ids.map(idArray => { // idArray is the inner ids array
      return idArray.map(id => products[id])
    })
    // so groupedByIds are the priced products grouped according to the id array
    // minimums are just a reduce on the inner arrays
    const minPricedProducts = groupedByIds.map(group => {
      // answer the member of group with the minimum price
      return group.reduce((acc, p) => acc.price < p.price ? acc : p);
    })
  }
}
```